# 2 web application points to same content db in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer

1. Is that possible that 2 or more web application in same farm can point to same content db, if yes Please let me know the procedure.
2. If the answer is no, Can you please tell me , Is that any way to synchronize 2 content db of different web applications of same farm, Please help me to achieve that.

Basically we wanted to run 2 separate web applications for intranet and internet purpose which should point to same content db of Intranet website.

Thanks

Comment: Could you consider using Web App Extension ?
Intranet => Web App 1 port 80 (authentication NTLM for example)
Extranet => Extend Web App 2 port 8080 (authentication as you wish)

Answer (score 2):

That's the purpose of the ability to extend a web application in SharePoint (associated with  Alternate Accessing Mapping)

You create your first web application, your intranet, assign it to a dedicated content database and do whatever you need to do. Later on you will extend the web application to another url. Both will point to the same content database but can have different authentication mechanism (I guess you won't ask people on the internet to connect through NTML if you were using that in your Intranet)

[image]

Please keep in mind the authentication mechanism, and the location of your server, usually intranet content / access will be located within your corporate network while a public (internet) site will be located outside (in your DMZ). How will the internet user reach your environment ? How will they authenticate themselve, etc.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276323%28v=office.14%29.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263256%28v=office.12%29.aspx